# What other ways to put connection string in vb web form via asp.net not to include the Drive C or D my db is ms access 2007

Tags: vb.net

Below is my connection string code in vb
the reason is that when I deploy this to web hosting there is no Drive D: or C: in website
anyone can help is really much appreciated, this is my first time to make a web program. 
Thank you very much in advance.

```
Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=D:\Desktop\Web1\Database\SignUp.accdb"
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly shouldn't be using a Access database in the first place. If your site is hosted then they would also provide database facilities, which probably means MySQL or maybe SQL Server. You ought to use one of those.

That said, if you're using Web Forms then you should be able to add an *App_Data* folder in the Solution Explorer and place the data file there, then specify the folder path using "|DataDirectory|", like [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/datadirectory-functionality/).

```
Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\SignUp.accdb"
```

EDIT: It just occurred to me that you're almost certainly not going to be able to use an ACCDB file regardless. If you were using an MDB file then you could use the Jet OLE DB provider, which is built into Windows. As you're using an ACCDB file, you need to use the ACE OLE DB provider, which is not part of Windows. That means that your host would have to either install Microsoft Office on their web server or else explicitly install the ACE provider, which Microsoft specify is not intended for servers. It can be installed but I very much doubt that any web host is going to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much  sir, but ms access database for web hosting is obsolete?

Comment: A proper RDBMS is always more robust than Access. Pretty much any web host will provide access to a proper RDBMS.

Comment: As of now sir I will just try my finished website to run to the world wide web thru web hosting if I successfully made it I wanna make a recopy in my program and use appropriate  RDBMS. my purpose is to see if  my program run well thru web hosting.

Comment: You can't run a web app on a host that doesn't support features that your app requires. You can't run a web app against an Access database if your host doesn't support the ACE provider. What you want is irrelevant to that. You should have done more research before creating the app. The good news is that ADO.NET code doesn't really change between databases, so switching your app to another database won't be difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much sir jmcilhinney. I change my DB now to .mdb for Jet.Oledb and I use this connection  Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\innerpitch.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Comment: It is completely running sir my next step now is to web host my website program but before that I will try to search a web host company that will cater ms access database, hopefully, again Thank you very much sir I really appreciate it..